# Should I post a question if I know the answer? Should I answer my own questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, best-practices, answers

Recently I had some questions and was going to post them here. While trying to find the best formulation for them I've found the answers.

Posting questions with immediate answers is welcome e.g. on [Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but this site is different.

I'm sure my questions are interesting and the answers can be useful for other people. Should I post them here? If yes, how to do that in the best way?

My question is similar to [this one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/is-it-okay-with-you-to-write-seed-questions) but I think the linked question is more about site promotion while mine is about knowledge sharing.

I don't want to flood the site with question&answers invented specially to "farm" reputation. There are some problems that were puzzling me. If I was able to find the answers myself, so what? Should I just wait for other people to ask the same?

The answers given to the question linked above are essentially "Pretend to not know the answer. People like answering questions". Well, I like answering questions too. Why not answer my own?

So, should I...

1. ... post such questions?
2. ... indicate that I already know the answer?
3. ... post my own answer?
4. ... give other people some time to answer the questions before posting my own answer?

Answer (score 4):

Seeding the site with questions is not ok, because it makes it grow artificially; now, when the site is a grown-up, it is perfectly ok, as long as:

- you ask serious questions,
- you won't flood the site with tens of them,
- you will be fair with accepting best answer.

Comment: Did you mean "as long as" instead of "unless"?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Fixed.

Comment: Well, this answers my question #1. So, provided my question fits all the requirements, should I pretend to not know the answer? What about questions #2, #3 and #4?

Comment: @MaksimZholudev #2 is covered by serious question, #3 & #4 by accepting best answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is the same discussion on biology BETA

https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/is-wikipedia-authoring-here-necessary-and-allowed

IMHO if you know you have solved a problem **of general interest** correctly it's ok, but wait with accepting the answer. If you know there is no single answer to that question, wait before answering yourself, otherwise it will often look like rep-gaiming and more important kill competition and therefore number and quality of answers. Someone may find a even better answer than yours, if the question is still open.