# Should I post a question with the intent to answer it myself?

Tags: discussion

I am asking because I have seen a couple misconceptions floating around on Physics.SE, but in a way so that it would be semi off-topic to address in answers to the post, and it is a bit too complex to get into in the comments (and also frustrating to do repeatedly).

I believe that the best way to treat this would be to post a well-designed question, provide a  thorough and cited answer and then be able to link to that when the question pops up.

I would of course hold out on accepting my own answer as a spur to others to provide better answers, but it would at least give the option to link to a more thorough discussion on SE. Would this be frowned upon?

It is similar to [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/should-i-post-a-question-if-i-know-the-answer-should-i-answer-my-own-questions) but different enough that I think it can still bear a little talking about.

Comment: *"What? What? Misconceptions? Here?"* Okay... If you've got enough time. I'll definitely enjoy these things ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's [perfectly fine to do so](https://physics.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer)

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

In fact you can post a question and its answer all at once:

[image]

See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: I prefer it if self-answers are posted as separate answers rather than as part of the question. That way, people can vote it up or down as normal and it still has to compete on a level playing field with any others which might get posted :)

Comment: @NickG if you do it the way I presented, the end result *is*, in fact a question with a separate answer. Answering *within* the question should always be avoided!