# Can I present an answer in the form of a leading question?

Tags: discussion, scope, answers, best-practices

Like "Jeopardy" presents answers in the form of questions can I post a physics question and post my own answer to it? The presentation I want to make is a new type of math method to calculate and compare worldlines in relativity. My question would be, "A new math method to calculate and compare worldlines in relativity? Any questions?" Then I'd explain the math method.

Comment: So you're just asking if it is valid to post a question and then answer it?

Comment: Oops, my question was answered here
https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1013/

Comment: The only caveats I will add here: if your Q&A only serves to have others check your work, then it will be closed as a homework question. And if your Q&A is only to present some new theory, it will be closed as non-mainstream. Self-answering doesn't get around the requirements for what questions will be on or off topic.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I will present it as a drab untilitarian math method and not discuss any physical implications of the math even if someone picks up on it.

Comment: @ralfcis In general, that makes a question off topic here.

Comment: So far so good, although the people engaged might disengage and I may not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Do you see my response or do I need @DavidZ for you to see it?

Comment: You mean your comment here? Yeah, I see it. No need to ping.

Comment: I assume you're saying anyone involved in a question, answer, or comment will get a notice that subsequent comments are pending. Sad because the people who answered my question aren't responding to my rebuttals to their answers. So I assume I use a bounty or rephrase the specifics in a new question or is persistence frowned upon and I should drop it as I'm often counselled to do.